# Debugging leak that seems to be from framework classes

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, profiling, memory-leaks

I've been profiling my app, looking for leaks. It wasn't long until I found some. I am getting multiple leaks from interaction with a UITableView. My first thought was obviously that I wasn't reusing the cells properly, but looking at this call stack it looks like something else, and checking the memory locations of cells as they are reused I can see the same cells are being recycled.

What should I be doing next to fix this memory leak? The leak is not occurring in my own code, so how should I go about fixing it? It's more than likely that it is the indirect result of my own mistakes, but how should I go about finding where these mistakes are?

Note that I have the same leaks whether running on simulator or device.

[image]

Comment: Since it seems to be related to a pan gesture, do you use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` anywhere?

Comment: @PhillipMills. No. I think that's something internal and related to the UIScrollView superclass of UITableView.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that.  :-)  Nothing reported by Product->Analyze?

Comment: @PhillipMills Analyse is clean. No issues.